# Error when I try to declare bag struct?

Tags: c, struct

bag-implementation.h:

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node *next;
  char *element;
  int repeats;
} Node;

typedef struct{
  size_t size;
  Node *head;
}Bag;
```

Line that errors in bag.c (which includes bag.h which includes bag-implementation.h):

```
Bag bag_union(Bag bag1, Bag bag2){
  Bag union;
  return bag1;

}
```

Error:

```
bag.c: In function 'bag_union':
bag.c:188:12: error: expected '{' before ';' token
bag.c:188:7: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
make: *** [bag.o] Error 1
```

If I try to compile without creating that bag, then it works fine. What is the issue?

Comment: You cannot have a variable called `union`.

Comment: lmao that fixed it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`union` is a reserved word in C, so you can't have a variable called like this. Simply rename it.

Answer (score 1):

`union` is a `keyword` it can't be used for variable.
  [This](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-variable-nameing-rules/) is the rule to define a variable.